# Unable to get text from a div element when text includes <br/>

Tags: protractor

using protractor 2 i was trying to get text from div elements having line break.

i've following HTML

```html
<tr class="abcde">
<td>
<div class="abc">London</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="abcde">
<td>
<div class="abc">
Washington DC
<br/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

i am able to get text from second div but second div returns blank value.

i'm using a code similar to one shown below :

```js
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='abc']")).getText().then(function(text){
  ourChoice = text.trim();
});
```

Can some one please suggest how could i get text from first div ?

Comment: attach your HTML code image here. Seems to be locator is incorrect

Comment: `element.all(by.css('div.abc')).first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ***div*** tags has same class name 'abc', so when we use your xpath, it will give two elements. In that cases we need to use element().all() and apply either first() or last() methods based on requirement. And you can apply each() method for looping.

Code Snippet:

**get first element Text**

```
element.all(by.xpath(".//div[@class='abc']")).first().getText().
            then(function(txt){
                     console.log(txt);
                 });
```

**get last element Text**

```
 element.all(by.xpath(".//div[@class='abc']")).last().getText().
            then(function(txt){
                      console.log(txt);
           });
```

**Looping**

```
element.all(by.xpath(".//div[@class='abc']")).each(function(ele,index){
                      ele.getText().then(function(txt){
                         console.log(txt);
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you Suresh and Gunderson. I've tried looping and getting first and last element text. in all cases, i get blank value for first div :(

Comment: you meant still you face issue?

Comment: yes.. i am not getting 'Washington DC' text from second div element. it returns me a blank value

Comment: Suresh, i will mark your reply as answer, as it has helped me to find the solution. Thanks again. :)